# Browse/Select Assemblies from the GAC or elsewhere

Tags: c#, assemblies, gac, openfiledialog

I need to allow users to select an assembly in much the same way that Visual Studio does. Either from the GAC or from anywhere else in the file system.

A simple OpenFileDialog will not suffice because navigating to c:\windows\assembly does not allow access to the actual file locations of the assemblies in the GAC.

I am not writing a Visual Studio plugin, so I cannot use DTE.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the CreateAssemblyEnum unmanaged API which returns the IAssemblyEnum interface.